# Questions about recommending a library cannot be deleted, because of an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, scope

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java) where the OP is asking to recommend a library, which is off-topic.

Shouldn't this and all duplicates be deleted? Because if this question is off-topic, also all duplicates must be off-topic.

It is not possible to vote-to-delete without finding another target for duplicates, but also this target must be off-topic.

It may be a duplicate, but there is no answer, so it doesn't give any answer.

Comment: It looks like the reason you can't vote to delete is because other questions have been closed as duplicates of it, not because it has an accepted answer. I don't think that having an accepted answer prevents deletion. Not sure, though.

Comment: this is a feature introduced about a year ago: [Users can't vote to delete posts that are the target of duplicate(s)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239597/152859)

Comment: But that means that it will be more and more question that are of topic

Comment: @jens seems to me that the course of action to take is to vote to delete all of them. Yank the tree, not just a branch. The answerless dupe target seems to say that too.

Comment: Are you reopening just to avoid the irony?

Comment: I just deleted one of the dupes and voted to delete the question.  Because rep, of course.